# Having trouble setting up react environment

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm learning ReactJS and tried to set up environment following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-vLtsKvp_4&t=300s)

but I get errors when i execute 'npm run it' command in cmd.
Here's  package.json file: 
`{
  "name": "react-folder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "it": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1"
  }
}`

[Errors](https://pastebin.com/V4VBJQXY)

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: click the link and u'll see them

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V4VBJQXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install webpack-cli` (if you are using older version of npm use `npm install webpack-cli --save` or you can just easily create react app with `npx create-react-app AppName`

Answer (score 0):

1st try installing webpack-cli as it's a requirement to run webpack now.

`npm i -D webpack-cli`